# Did Galois show $5^\sqrt{2}$ can't solve a high-order integer polynomial?

Tags: galois-theory

Suppose you have an unlimited quantity of the number one, and the operators plus, minus, multiply, divide, and power. Consider the (countable) set $S$ you generate by combining these:

- Using just one and plus, you can construct the natural numbers.
- Using minus, you can construct the integers.
- Using divide, you can construct the rational numbers.
- Using power, you can construct nth roots like $2^{1/2} = \sqrt{2}$

So far, so good. However, you can now go further and construct things
like $5^\sqrt{2}$ and far more bizarre things. Questions:

- Did Galois show $S$ is a proper subset of the algebraic numbers? I
  know he showed arbitrary 5th-degree polynomials don't have "closed-
  form" solutions, but I believe his definition of "closed form" was
  more limited.
- If not, let $T$ be the set of numbers Galois considers "closed
  form". Are there members of $S-T$ that solve high order polynomials?
- $S$ seems like an "obvious" set to me. Does it have a name, and do 
  people study it?
- I chose $5^\sqrt{2}$ as a "random example": it seems obvious that 
  it's non-algebraic, but I can't seem to prove it.

Comment: $5^{\sqrt 2}$ is transcendental, via [Gelfond-Schneider](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GelfondsTheorem.html).

Comment: Solutions to the quintic do have closed forms, but in general one requires hypergeometric or theta functions to express them (much like trigonometric functions turn up in solving the cubic).

Comment: Galois's work does not deal with $S$. The set $S$ contains transcendental numbers, for instance your $5^{\sqrt{2}}$. Since $S$ is countable, "most" transcendental numbers are not in $S$. I know nothing about the intersection of $S$ and the algebraic numbers.  There is a limited number of results that could be thought of as being about $S$, having to do with algebraic independence.

Comment: Galois' work is not really about these matters.

Comment: Isn't this closure you described the *Exponential closure* of the rationals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that your set $S$ is the set some people call "the elementary numbers." There are some papers about this: Tim Chow, [What is a closed-form number?](http://www-math.mit.edu/~tchow/closedform.pdf), Amer Math Monthly, 1999; aargh, my internet connection just vanished, so I can't copy out any more, but I typed "elementary number" into Google Scholar and a bunch of likely papers came up.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you!